# Upgrade domain selection for service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

If I have say few upgrade domains in service fabric. how does service fabric selects upgrade domains while performing upgrades?

Comment: I updated my answer, please review below.

Answer (score 1):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade#rolling-upgrades-overview

> Update domains do not receive updates in a particular order.

However, using the [start-servicefabricclusterupgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/start-servicefabricclusterupgrade) commandlet, you can specify `-SortOrder`, which

> Defines the order in which an upgrade proceeds through the cluster.

Note that `Default`

> Indicates that the default sort order (as specified in cluster manifest) will be used.

In my experience (mostly on-prem standalone clusters) for *Configuration* updates, I'm 99% sure it does them in sequential order: UD0, UD1, etc.